# Proper prevention of mail injection in PHP

Tags: php, sendmail, email

Could you advise me how do I go about preventing [email injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_injection) in PHP `mail()` without losing original message data? E.g. if I need to allow user to use `\r\n`, `To`, `CC` etc, so I do not want to completely strip them away from the message - I still want them delivered, but without adding any additional headers or somehow allowing mail injection to happen.

Most of the advices on internet suggest stripping that data away completely - but I do not want to do that.

I am sending plain text (non HTML) messages through PHP `mail()` function.

What would you advise?

Comment: `To:` and `CC:` are headers - you can't maintain functionality by removing them. I'm not sure what you're asking here. Provide a sample of your initial idea and we'll try to steer you in the right direction :-).

Comment: Where are you using user-supplied data?  Just in the message body?

Comment: @drrcknlsn User-supplied data is in the message body and recipient e-mail.

Comment: @Matt I am mailing arbitrary user-supplied data and from what I understand, users can "inject" their own headers when I use their input data in message body causing the mail to be re-routed to other e-mail address other than intended, etc.

Comment: See this article for more information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_injection

Comment: This is normally escaped by using a function like `mail()` the content is differentiated from the headers itself.

Comment: I am using mail() function already. It says on the internet this function does not prevent mail injection.

Comment: Hmm weird, I am sure somewhere it said that later PHP did, but have you ready this: http://www.damonkohler.com/2008/12/email-injection.html

Comment: @Atern: It prevents injection of headers through the _message body_, but not through the _additional headers_ argument.  See my answer below with how to deal with this for email headers like `From` and such.

Comment: Yea so this solvable if you never use user defined extra headers, in which case it should be fine for you if your not.

Comment: Thank you Sammaye, you were right, mail() prevents injection in mail body.

Comment: what does mail() do to prevent injection in the body?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To filter valid emails for use in the recipient email field, take a look at [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php):

```
$email = filter_var($_POST['recipient_email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if ($email === FALSE) {
    echo 'Invalid email';
    exit(1);
}
```

This will make sure your users only supply singular, valid emails, which you can then pass to the `mail()` function.  As far as I know, there's no way to inject headers through the message body using the PHP `mail()` function, so that data shouldn't need any special processing.

**Update:**

According to [the documentation for `mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), when it's talking directly to an SMTP server, you will need to prevent full stops in the message body:

```
$body = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $body);
```

**Update #2:**

Apparently, it's also possible to inject via the subject, as well, but since there is no `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL_SUBJECT`, you'll need to do the filtering yourself:

```
$subject = str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", '%0A', '%0D'), '', $_POST['subject']);
```

Comment: Thank you, but on the Internet it says that it is possible to inject headers into the message body using mail() function.

Comment: However, thank you for the filter_var function. I am going to use it instead of regular expression I am using.

Comment: @Atern Note filter_var does have some limitations on what emails it allows which is why I still use regex for email validation, I use: http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail

Comment: @Sammaye, thanks, great article, this is better than basic regex I was using before.

Comment: @Atern: The only way to inject headers is through the _additional headers_ argument.  Usually this is done via the `From` header, as that's the most common header provided in the additional headers argument.

Comment: Here it is describes how it is possible to inject additional headers when user input data is entered in message body: http://www.damonkohler.com/2008/12/email-injection.html.

Comment: @Atern: That article injects via the `From` header for every example.  Read it carefully.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you you want to put the email address of the visitor in the optional header field like so:

```
$headers = "From: $visitorEmailAddress";
```

However, if

> $visitorEmailAddress

contains

> "address@email.com\n\nBCC:spam@v1agra.com"

you've made yourself a spam host, opening the door for mail injection.
This is a very simple example, but creative spammers and malicious hackers can sneak potentially damaging scripts in your email, since email is sent as a plaintext file. Even attachments are converted plaintext, and they can easily send attachements by adding a mimetype content line.

If your form validation for the FROM and/or TO fields is OK, you have to look at the form validation for the body of the email. I'd strip out the '-=' and '=-' characters, and prevent users from typing plain HTML by using `strip_tags()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for a review of various options:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/428076/PHP-Mail-Injection-Protection-and-E-Mail-Validatio

It covers several options and tries to explain the benefits and risks of each.

Answer (score 0):

Use a designated mime email library, like [`Mail_Mime`](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php):

```
<?php
include 'Mail.php';
include 'Mail/mime.php' ;

$mime = new Mail_mime();

$mime->setTXTBody("Message goes here");
$hdrs = $mime->headers(array(
    'From'    => 'you@yourdomain.com',
    'Subject' => 'Test mime message'
));
$body = $mime->get();

$mail = &Mail::factory('mail');
$mail->send('postmaster@localhost', $hdrs, $body);

?>
```