# In mail() function, 'From:' displays only the first world

Tags: php, email

I have this code, that is supposed to send a mail to an address. The problems is: in the header i'm supposed to get the name like "Bob Marley" for instance, but it says "(unknown sender)" if the name is greater then one word. If the name is exactly one word, it works. If i concatenate the $_POST['nume'] value to the $message, it's all there. For some reason, in the header, it does not work like it should.

```
<form name="contact" method="post" class="clearfix" id="formular">
   <input class="inputC" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" id="numeCo" onClick="clearValue(this.id)" onBlur="testValue(this.id)" name="nume"/>

   <input class="inputC" type="text" placeholder="E-mail Address" id="adresaCo" onClick="clearValue(this.id)" onBlur="testValue(this.id)" name="adrMail"/>

   <input class="inputC" type="text" placeholder="What services do you need?" id="serviciiCo" onClick="clearValue(this.id)" onBlur="testValue(this.id)" name="servicii"/>

   <div class="sumarise">
   <textarea class="textAreaC" placeholder="Please summarize your project..." id="textArCo" onClick="clearValue(this.id)" onBlur="testValue(this.id)" name="descriere"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="sB clearfix">
   <input class="submitC" type="submit" value="Send Message" />
   </div>                              
   </form>
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['nume'], $_POST['adrMail'], $_POST['descriere']))
    {
     /*echo "<script> return checkForm();</script>";*/
     $to = "radu.mircea.andrei@gmail.com";                                                                              
     $subject = $_POST['servicii'];
     $message = $_POST['descriere'];                                        
     $name = $_POST['nume'];
     $headers= "From: ".$name."\n".'Reply-To: '.$_POST['adrMail'];
     mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);                                      
    }
  ?>
```

Comment: try using \r\n instead of just \n in the headers.

Comment: try using PHPMailer, it is easier to use and to configure.

Comment: This form is subject to hacking vulnerabilities

Comment: @MihaiIorga, not to mention swiftmailer.org
I have been using that one alot.

Comment: There is a RFC for a reason. If you throw around with undefined data, why do you expect it work?

Comment: use @Sohnee answer: $header="From: ".$_POST['nume']."<".$_POST['adrMail'].">\r\n";

Comment: There is a constant PHP_EOL fyi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to put this as answer because I think it is quite important for you to note.

There is a vulnerability when using the `mail()` function as you are with user defined `From` headers. See this question here: [Proper prevention of mail injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952473/proper-prevention-of-mail-injection-in-php/11952659#comment15926336_11952659)

However to solve your actual problem:

- Try using \r\n as well (like @Sudhir said) (I find \r\n is more compliant with some mail clients)
- Put in a email too like @Sohnee says

Comment: This came as a late reply, but thank you for the link. It is indeed important to know.

Answer (score 2):

The "to" address needs to conform to [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) - perhaps the from address does also:

```
From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>
```

See the [PHP Mail examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

The PHP documentation also states that `\n` should be valid and is recommended if you have trouble with `\r\n` - so I think it is unlikely that this is the problem, although there is no harm in trying that too.

Comment: I know this came as a late reply, but thank you for answering.