# Email not sending when using variables in header

Tags: php

I am creating a contact form and for some reason when I use variables int he header, the email isn't getting sent.
This one works:

```
$first_name = (isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : null);
$last_name = (isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : null);
$email = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null);
$message = (isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : null);
$mail_to = "MyEmail";
$subject = "Subject";
$headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$first_name.' '.$last_name.' <info@email.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers)
```

and this one doesn't

```
$first_name = (isset($_POST['firstname']) ? $_POST['firstname'] : null);
$last_name = (isset($_POST['lastname']) ? $_POST['lastname'] : null);
$email = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null);
$message = (isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : null);
$mail_to = "MyEmail";
$subject = "Subject";
$headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$first_name.' '.$last_name.' <'.$email.'>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($mail_to, $subject, $message, $headers)
```

I am talking about these lines:

```
$headers .= 'From: '.$first_name.' '.$last_name.' <info@email.com>'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$first_name.' '.$last_name.' <'.$email.'>'."\r\n";
```

This works until I add the email variable into the headers, could someone explain me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Next port of call... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952473/proper-prevention-of-mail-injection-in-php

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the variable inside Your name <>

Comment: Could you elaborate on that as I don't really get what you mean