# Adding auto reply mail to php contact form

Tags: php, html

I've adapted a simple contact form using php which works fine. However I now need to add an auto response email, so when the client has entered details into the form it not only sends me the details, but sends the client a html email response.

Can any of you kind clever people point me in the right direction on how to achieve this as I'm stuck. Below is the code I'm using; am I right in thinking I need to use another "if" statement to send auto reply?

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
 <?php

 if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
 empty($_POST['email'])     ||
 empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
 empty($_POST['message'])   ||
 !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
 {
 echo "No arguments Provided!";
 return false;
 }

 $name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
 $email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
 $phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
 $message = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']));


 $to = 'andy@andydry.com'; 
 $email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
 $email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact 
 form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: 
 $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
 $headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; 
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";
 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
 return true;

 ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by an "auto reply"?  You currently have code which sends an email, and it sounds like you're asking how to write code which sends an email.  In what way would this other one be different from what you already have?  It's not really clear what the problem is.

Comment: Currently the script above sends me an email with the client's details from the online form, which uses pop up CSS to say message sent successfully. I want in the same script to send the client an automated email which provides them with further information about the product they are interested in. At the moment I'm having to send the email to the client manually if that makes sense?

Comment: So what is the actual problem?  You have code which sends an email, and you want to write code which sends an email.  Have you tried... writing that code?  Is something not working?  You're not really presenting us with a problem, you're just asking us to write a new feature on your website for you.

Comment: Hold on David, I've stated that I have adapted a simple form which provides me an email with the clients details... The problem is that I'm wanting to add a function which automatically sends another email to the client with info on it. I'm not asking you to right any code for me I'm just wanting some advice on how to do go about adding this in my current code.

Comment: You'd go about it by editing the code to do what you want it to do.  You're asking how to write code which sends an email, but you're showing us code which sends an email.  What about this code do you not understand?  When you modify it to do what you want, is it not working in some way?  I don't know how else to explain this... You *already have* everything you need.  So what's the actual problem?

Comment: Sorry David, I don't know how else to put it any simpler. Other users have given some info that I can work on now. I appreciate your time sorry I couldn't explain it any clearer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Send another email, but to the client, when the first email is sent successfully. That is assuming you're sending the client an email with different content than you're sending yourself when they use the contact form. Otherwise, use BCC.

Also, use a mail library such as Swiftmailer.

Comment: Thanks tdoggy! Swiftmailer looks brilliant. Was looking at Mailchimp etc but Swiftmailer seems better

Comment: Yeah, I've used swiftmailer and it's pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

*First off, a caveat:* the php mail() function is prone to header-injection abuse, which can be used to force your mail server to spam emails on spammers behalf.  [Strictly filter incoming email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952473/proper-prevention-of-mail-injection-in-php)

As far as your question, you seem to be wanting to add a CC to your email of the customer's email address.

That is done through adding to the headers:

```
 $headers .= "CC: ".$customer_email_address_sanitized_and_escaped."\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks Kzqai, never thought of adding "CC". The security info is much appreciated as well.