# PHP Contact Form Best Practice: Input Validation not working

Tags: php, forms, code-injection

My form input validation is not working as I expect it to work.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Kontaktformular'; 
$to = 'meine@mail.de'; 
$subject = 'Kontaktformular';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
```

In this Part I try to validate the input:

```
$email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if ($email === FALSE) {
    echo 'Invalid email';
    exit(1);
}

$body = str_replace("\n.", "\n..", $body);
```

Now I try to send the mail if the input is not NULL:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    echo '<p>Message was sent!</p>';
    } else {
    echo '<p>Something went wrong :( Please try again</p>';
    }
} else {
    die ("Direct access not allowed!");
}
?>
```

My Problem is, that my the code returns either "Invalid email" or "Direct access not allowed!", but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

My HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="php-contact.php" class="animated fadeIn">
<label>Name</label>
<input name="name" placeholder="Name">

<label>E-Mail</label>
<input name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-Mail, zum antworten&hellip;">

<label>Nachricht</label>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Nachricht&hellip;"></textarea>

<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Absenden">
</form>
```

I tried to use these code examples:
[Proper prevention of mail injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952473/proper-prevention-of-mail-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing the processing in the wrong order. You need firstly to check that the various form fields are present within the POSTed data before trying to assign to variables which then get used to construct the message.

```
<?php
    /* test METHOD and if fields are present in POST array */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['submit'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['message'] ) ){

        /* do some sanitation and validation on user input */
        $name=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $email=filter_var( filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL ), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
        $message=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

        /* if the sanitation and validation succeeds, continue processing */
        if( $name && $email && $message ){

            $from = 'From: Kontaktformular'; 
            $to = 'meine@mail.de'; 
            $subject = 'Kontaktformular';

            $body = "From: $name\nE-Mail: $email\nMessage:\n $message"; 

            $status=mail( $to, $subject, $body, $from );
            echo $status ? '<p>Message was sent!</p>' : '<p>Something went wrong :( Please try again</p>';

        } else {
            echo "bogus!"
        }

    } else {
        die("Direct access not allowed!");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the misleading error message you went with, this is your problem:

```
isset($_POST['Submit'])
```

Because the form input is:

```
<input name="submit">
```

Those things are case-sensitive.

#### How can you debug this?

- First of all, `print_r($_POST);` to see what you actually got.
- Secondly, avoid `isset()` until you ensured that things are working. Supressing *useful* notices is never a good strategy.

Answer (score 0):

here is another example how you could build this validate script. Note I would recommend to send the mail body as text/plain so that your email client does not interpret any bogus html. Also I have added some max length checks so that the user can not submit data with an arbitrary length.

```
<?php

// check request method
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Invalid request method');
}

// get all input vars
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
$message = isset($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : null;

// validate values
if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($message)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Invalid values provided');
}

if (strlen($name) > 64) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Name can have max 64 chars');
}

if (strlen($email) > 32) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Email can have max 32 chars');
}

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Invalid email format');
}

if (strlen($message) > 1023) {
    throw new \RuntimeException('Message can have max 1023 chars');
}

// send mail
$headers = "From: your@email.com" . "\r\n";
$headers.= "Content-Type: text/plain";
$to = "meine@mail.de";
$subject = "Kontaktformular";
$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo '<p>Message was sent!</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>Something went wrong :( Please try again</p>';
}
```